# Understanding the unit used to measure the estimate of population density of bears

Tags: population, ecology

I do not have a strong stats background, so I apologize in advance if this is a silly question.

I'm currently reading about population density for wildlife. I've read a paper that reports the population density of bears as "bears / 1000 km2 of habitat". I am confused by this unit of measurement. I understand that population density is calculated as "total population / area", in this case "bears / area". What I don't understand is the use of "per 1000 km2", despite reading the paper thoroughly.

Why is this population density reported as "bears / 1000 km2" instead of simply "bears / km2"?

Paper: https://pubs.aina.ucalgary.ca/arctic/Arctic48-2-147.pdf

Comment: Because the habitat area is measured in "$1000~\textrm{km}^2$" units.

Comment: You are encountering a *scaling factor* in the denominator. You encounter these every day in terms like "sixty percent" which is 0.60 × a scaling factor of 100.

Comment: Probably to avoid small decimal numbers, like 0.032 bears/km$^2$. The same reason why disease prevalence is usually given as x in 100,000, or why people use percentages instead of simple fractions.

Comment: ... or perhaps bear scientists prefer the little-known unit of length, the "ursimeter," equal to $31.62278$ kilometers.  The population density is given in bears per square ursimeter (because one square ursimeter is $31.62278^2 = 1000$ square kilometers).

Comment: @IgorF. Thank you for the explanation. I now understand why they use this measurement. I still struggle to understand how they calculate this. Do they simply do "counts / total km2" and then multiply by 1000 km2 to get bears / 1000 km2?

Comment: I don't *know* how they do it, but your "algorithm" would work, too.

Comment: It is often convenient to express numerical results in a #.## numerical format, rather than a 0.0000### format, or a ###00000 format. For example, if one's results are on the order of 0.0000###, one may simply multiply them all by 100,000 and report #.## per 100,000.